# Comparing two tables and returning answers that do not appear in both in mysql

Tags: mysql

The problem I am having is in relation to comparing two tables, and returning results which do not feature in both tables. I am using a theatre based situtation with bookings and seat numbers.

So my first table is the **seat** table looking like this.

```
row_no     area_name
 a01       front stalls
 a02       front stalls
```

there are several area names that can be used, but they all use the same format as the above. For this example I will use seats a01 through a20 only in the *front stalls*.

The second table is the **booking** table looking like this

```
ticket_no    row_no    date_time       customer_name
 001070714    a01      21:00 7.7.14    John Doe
 002070714    a02      21:00 7.7.14    John Doe
```

What I am trying to achieve is to compare the list of booked seats at that specific showtime to the total list of seats from the seat table, then group the results by area_name so I hopefully acheive results like

```
area_name       row_no
front stalls    18
```

where 18 would be the number of free seats from the complete set of 20 described in the seat table.

How would I set about achieving this answer?

EDIT
This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT
DISTINCT s.area_name, row_no
FROM seat AS s
FROM booking AS b
COUNT * WHERE s.row_no != b.row_no
WHERE b.title = rammstein
WHERE s.area_name = 'front stalls'
GROUP BY s.area_name;
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: several iterations among a similar theme,

`SELECT
     DISTINCT s.area_name, s.row_no
     FROM seat AS a, booking AS b,
     COUNT * WHERE s.row_no != b.row_no
     WHERE b.date_time = '21:00, 7.7.14'
     WHERE s.area_name = 'front stalls';`

is what I used last.

Comment: What did you get with this last try?

Comment: Your dates/times are really store as datetimes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT seat_q.area_name, (seat_q.num_seats - COUNT(*) AS occupied_seats) AS free_seats
FROM booking b
WHERE row_no IN (
    SELECT s.row_no 
    FROM seat s
    WHERE s.area_name = 'front stalls'
    GROUP BY s.area_name)
JOIN
(SELECT s.row_no, s.area_name, COUNT(s.*) AS num_seats
 FROM seat s
 WHERE s.area_name = 'front stalls'
 GROUP BY s.area_name) AS seat_q
ON seat_q.row_no = b.row_no
WHERE b.date_time = '21:00, 7.7.14'
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an incorect syntax error near 
`'*) - COUNT(b.*)) AS free_seats
FROM seat s
JOIN booking b ON s.row_no = b.row_no' at line 1`
I'm not sure if this error is refferencing to the line with the alias command or the `From seat s` command.

Comment: I have just changed my answer.